# Given any 2 curves, can we prove the existence of a common normal?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, curves, algebraic-curves, tangent-line

One suggestion would be to say the every two curves will have a distance of closest approach, and this distance will be normal to both of them, but this is either:
1)what we are actually trying to prove
2) inherently wrong in the sense, there maybe 2 curves who don't have a common normal so their distance of closest approach wouldn't be normal to them.

Comment: Is the idea that the curves are closed?

Comment: @CadeReinberger I'm not exactly sure in what cases to divide the problem into. But yes, if it helps we can solve it differently in open-open, closed-closed, and open-closed cases

Comment: If both can be open you have cases like $y = e^x$ and $y = e^{-x}$ where the two curves do not even have a pair of normals that are parallel.

Comment: @DavidK good insight. Can you name a few more, I'm really interested in their nature.

Comment: @Mohammad has answered the open-closed case, interestingly. I asked the closed-ness question because I suspect that for two smooth closed curves the answer is actually  in the affirmative.

Comment: @CadeReinberger my intuition says so tio

Comment: @CadeReinberger I think an argument is possible using solid angles

Comment: $y=x^3$ and $y=-x^3$ have slopes of tangents (normals) $y'=3x_0^2 \ (y'_n=-\frac1{3x_0^2})$ and $y'=-3x_1^2 \ (y'_n=\frac1{3x_1^2})$, but $-\frac1{3x_0^2}\ne \frac1{3x_1^2}$. You can generalize this result to any odd power.

Comment: @DavidK any such examples with non intersecting curves? Reason being that I'm working with closest assistance of approach, so that question doesn't arrive in the case of intersecting curves

Comment: You could try the curves $y=e^x$ and $y=-e^x$, which was the example I actually first thought of, not sure why I changed it. Those curves do not intersect but they also have no point of closest approach.

Answer (score 2):

If $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$ are two closed smooth curves in the plane then they have $\geq1$ common normals.

*Proof.* The function
$$f(p,q):=\bigl\{|q-p|\bigm| p\in\gamma_1, \ q\in\gamma_2\bigr\}$$
takes a positive maximum at some point $(p_0,q_0)$ of the compact set $\gamma_1\times\gamma_2$. The line $\ell:=p_0\vee q_0$ then is a common normal to both $\gamma_i$, since otherwise there would be points $p'\in\gamma_1$  and $q'\in\gamma_2$ near $p_0$ and $q_0$ with $|q'-p'|>|q_0-p_0|$.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little on how suppose p naught and q naught are not normal then that implies there exists another maximum. I'm having trouble comprehending it goemetrically

Comment: @John_Nash: You have appealed to this principle in your question. If $\ell$ would not be normal to $\gamma_1$ at $p_0=\gamma_1(t_0)$ then the function $f(t):=|\gamma_1(t)-q_0|^2$ would not have a maximum at $t=t_0$, since $f'(t_0)\ne0$.

Answer (score 1):

If they have parallel tangents at a point, then they have the same normal at that point.

So you only need to differentiate.

Comment: This provides us with a method of checking. But can we classify beforehand, fir examples will 2 non intersecting curves always have a common normal?

Comment: @John_Nash I don't understand. As for your question, my answer above does not assume that the curves intersect. Indeed, when I said that they should have the same tangent, I actually meant same as in *parallel,* not necessarily coincident. Thus, if your curves have the same derivative at a point, then they necessarily have parallel tangents, and therefore coincident normals, there.

Comment: yes thanks for that this provides a convenient method for checking whether two curves will have a common normal or not. Now, is there a general family of curves(for example maybe closed curves) such that if we take any two curves from that family, they will have a common normal?

Comment: @John_Nash That's a different question, but off the top of my head I can't presently think of a reason why such a system of curves may not exist. Indeed, I can noe say that such a system exists. Think of two curves that have a common normal. But of course I guess you mean an infinite family.

Answer (score 0):

What about orthogonal trajectories?

Each family member is normal to the other family member so they do not have a common normal.

Comment: Every two concentric circles do have a common normal, it is radius of the biggest circle

Comment: @John_Nash I think he means that, say, the unit circle and the positive $x$ axis don't have a common normal

Comment: @CadeReinberger the y axis?

Comment: @John_Nash. Yup. Dunno how I missed it.